# Stop Kendo Grid to make server call while moving to first page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid with AutoBind(false) option. Now i fill data in kendo grid based on user's criteria. Now issue is that when I apply following code it makes two server side call.

```
$("#KendoListData").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
$('#KendoListData').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.page(1);
```

And when I debugged the code, I found that `$('#KendoListData').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.page(1);` statement fire server call.

So is there anyway to stop server call and move to first page?

Comment: Both lines of code force a read of the DataSource. Remove the first line, `$('#KendoListData').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.page(1);` is all you need, it will refresh the datasource and set the grid to page 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use client side paging by turning serveroperations off at the datasource.

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
  .Ajax()
  .ServerOperation(false)
  ...)
```

But now all data is send to the client not just the currently displayed page/filter/group.

Answer (score 0):

Use dataBound and set page number, it wont makes two server side call.

```
$('#KendoListData').data('kendoGrid').one("dataBound", function() {
                this.dataSource.page(2);
});
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Can't use it. It'll execute for each item of datalist.